# Basis of $V=\{a\cdot(1,2,3)^T\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

I've a vector space

$V=\left\{a\left(\begin{array}
 {l}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{array}\right)\right\}$ $a$ is any real number.

Can I choose it's basis as $\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{array}\right)$.

I think that it spans the space but then I can also have it's basis the set of these three vectors
$\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$
$\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right)$$\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$.

Something is wrong with my logic. Can anyone please point out my error.

Thank you

Comment: Clearly the set does can only span $\mathbb{R}$, so the your vector cannot be a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: @ObsessiveInteger That's not what OP was asking. They are not asking if the vector can be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I was just pointing that out since he wrote a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: I changed your title, keep the vertical span of titles reasonable, else it messes up with the question page composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the set $A$ containing only one element, $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}$, is indeed a basis for $V$. It is very easy to show that the set satisfies both conditions that are in the definition of basis:

1. It is true that the span of $A$ is equal to $V$, i.e. $\mathrm{span}(A)=V$.
2. It is true that the set $A$ is linearly independent.

---

On the other hand, the set $B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, containing the three vectors you list is **not** a basis for $V$, because the first condition fails. The span of $B$ includes the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ which is **not** an element of $V$. This means that the span is **not** equal to $V$, so $B$ cannot be a basis for $V$.

Comment: Thank you, could you comment on the first part of my question?

Comment: @Kashmiri I expanded my answer, it should now explain everything.

Comment: Yes you can @Kashmiri

Comment: So the basis vector should be in the original vector space to be a basis

Comment: @Kashmiri It is true that if a set $B$ is a basis for the vector space $V$, then $B$ must be a subset of $V$, yes. Note that the reverse is far from true, i.e., just because $B$ is a subset of $V$, it doesn't mean it is a basis.

Comment: Thank you so much :) .